# Getting cell location of recently activated hyperlink in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am working with excel with multiple work sheets. sheet1 contains some data & hyper links to remaining sheets. So once any one hyperlink activated its changing current active sheet. Now,how can i go to previous working cell, where hyperlink exists (Like "GO BACK"). I want to keep "go back" button in remaining sheets, so it will redirect to recently activated hyperlink in sheet1.

Answer (score 0):

You can get that information from the `Target.Range.Address`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    Debug.Print Target.Range.Address
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Siddharth's answer - put this in a code module:

```
Public bklnk As Worksheet

Sub GoBack()
    bklnk.Activate
End Sub
```

And put this in the code area of any sheet you have which has hyperlinks:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    Set bklnk = Me
End Sub
```

Then put your 'Go Back' button on each sheet wherever you want it and link it to the GoBack macro.

Clicking go back on each page should return you to the cell with the link you just followed.